# Connect 4G router to multiple devices via Ethernet cable

Tags: router, ethernet, switch, cable

I have a 4G router (Huawei e5172) with one LAN port (DHCP enabled). I need to connect 3 PCs and 1 wireless access point to this router via Ethernet so I got a 5-port Ethernet switch and connected it to the 4G router, and the 4 devices with Ethernet cables.

The connection works when I plug the 4G router directly to one of the PCs, but the problem is that I'm not getting any connectivity on any of the devices. I keep getting the following message "Can't resolve controller DNS" on the access point.

I'm not too savvy with networks, is there anything wrong I'm doing? How can I achieve connecting these devices to the 4G router via Ethernet cables?

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

There are quite a lot of things to check:-

- Are you using the correct uplink port on the switch to connect to the router?
- Most Ethernet switches have LEDs to show connectivity: are these lighting?
- Are you using straight, not crossed cables (though you may need a crossed cable for the access point)?
- Leave the wireless access point disconnected initially, as if wrongly configured it may have its own DHCP server competing with that on the router.
- Compare the PC's IP configuration when plugged into the router and into the switch: both should have the same subnet address (typically **192.168.N.*x*** - the first three numbers should be the same, but the *x* may vary); the DNS server should be the same (typically **192.168.N.1**).
- If plugging in the access point stops the other PCs from working, and the switch LED shows a valid connection, then you will need to follow the AP configuration instructions to set it up correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the help. To answer these points: The switch's manual states that "all ports on the switch support auto-MDI/MDI-X functionality, so crossover cables and uplink ports are not needed for connections to PCs, routers, hubs, additional switches or other devices." Lights are all green and blinking. I'm using straight cables all throughout. I've tried connecting only one PC to the switch and the LAN shows no connectivity (yellow triangle) on the PC. The gateway IP is 192.168.1.1 and the PC's IP is 192.168.1.2. I'm not sure what other tests I can do to pinpoint the problem further.

Comment: That all looks OK. Is there any difference in IP settings when directly connected to the router?

Comment: No they're the same when I do cmd > ipconfig /all

Comment: What is the DNS setting on the PC connected through the switch? Can you ping to 8.8.8.8?

Comment: In that case I can see no reason that they would not be working. Try **Repair** on the internet connection when connected through the switch, and note any error messages. After that I am running out of ideas.

Comment: It might be that the IP address it has when connecting via the switch is left over from when it was connected directly.  If you can do the *Repair* as suggested, and it doesn't get an IP, the problem is between the switch and the router.

Comment: @Paul If the settings are "left over" it won't matter, provided the subnet is correct. What is important is that the AP is disconnected (preferably switched off, so that the Ethernet-connected PCs will not try to connect via the disconnected wireless).

Comment: @AFH it matters in that it might appear that DHCP is working, while it is not really.

Comment: @Paul - No, because we already know that this configuration works on a direct connection to the router, so it should work equally well through the switch, just as if it were manually configured.

Comment: @AFH No, we don't know whether the switch is introducing a problem, and until the IP is confirmed as being issued by the router while connected through the switch, or remaining in effect from just being replugged from the router to switch.  Until we know if there is *any* traffic coming via the switch, we cannot pinpoint the issue.  Your suggestion of the repair will let us know that.

Comment: I did repair connection and the problem still persisted. I replaced the switch with an ethernet router and all worked perfectly. I'm still baffled though how come the 4G router's DHCP wasn't assigning IPs although it was enabled for the LAN network. Thanks all for the help!

Comment: My only other thoughts are (1) to see if the 4G router has a screen to show connected devices and (2) to check if the switch is more than just a simple switch and is acting as a network bridge mode, and therefore needs its own DHCP.